# HashSet Null Pointer Exception in Android but doesn't occur in java. why?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null

I was working with hashsets and somehow i came across NPE. I know hashset allow null values. So i tried to know what exactly happening and i created following code in java(just for learning purpose)

Java Code -

```
public class numbers {
static HashSet<String> s = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        s.add("a");
        s.add(null);
        s.add("b");
        for(String l:s)
        {
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}
```

It gave me no exceptions. The output is printed to the console. Then i tried to run the same code in android

Android Code -

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    HashSet<String> s = new HashSet<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        s.add("a");
        s.add(null);
        s.add("b");

        for(String l:s)
        {
            //System.out.println(l);
            Log.i("ExceptionCheck", l);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i run the application . Null pointer exception is raised at Log statement, where i am trying to read the output.

Can anyone explain me whats the difference ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have added a `null` to your set and then you're printing the values.

You cannot pass a `null` message to any of the `Log` print calls such as [`Log.i()`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/util/Log.java#159). It will [NPE with message "println needs a message"](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_util_Log.cpp#108).

However, something like this works that ensures the message is not null:

```
Log.i("ExceptionCheck", "" + l);
```

Comment: Thanks. Lesson Learnt

Answer (score 4):

That is because `s.add(null);` line

`Console` allow `null` values but Logcat doesn't